# Garbage Collector - Log Analyzer for large files

Tags: java, garbage-collection, g1gc

I'd like to analyse a "large" G1 - Garbage Collection Logfile (appr. 500.000 lines). Therefore I'm looking for a freeware-tool which is able to open and analyze such large files. Yet I use GCViewer 1.32 but it seems that this program is not able to open my file. There is no error message but nothing happens when I try to open the logfile. Does somebody know a good tool for my problem?

Best Regards,
AnarchoEnte

Comment: If you can, I would memory profile your application.  This is the best place to start before tuning the GC IMHO.

Comment: My target is currently not to tune the GC but to analyze how the G1 is working

Comment: Very few tools have support for G1. It has a very different, much more verbose output.  I suggest you have a look at this presentation.  https://plus.google.com/u/1/102874451454074733659/posts/SKAqZHLwFyT Kirk discusses what the part of the G1 logs mean.

Comment: you can use eclipse memory analyzer tool. http://www.eclipse.org/mat/downloads.php

Answer (score 2):

GarbageCat parses Java garbage collection logging and provides analysis to support JVM tuning and troubleshooting for OpenJDK and Sun JDK. It differs from other tools in that it goes beyond the simple math of calculating statistics such as maximum pause time and throughput.

Comment: GarbageCat seems to be cool. Is it possible, that it does not support the "-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps" - option within a log?

Comment: GarbageCat is best utilized with the following GC logging options:
      -XX:+PrintGC -Xloggc:gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [GCViewer](https://github.com/chewiebug/GCViewer/wiki)? I guess it should work for you.

Comment: GCViewer is not able to open my file ... I think it's too large

Comment: I am not sure why you are not able to... for me it has always worked.

Comment: I try to open the file and nothing happens. Even I wait 5 minutes ... For smaller logfiles it always worked fine. But if the file is larger than ~200.000 lines nothing happens

Comment: It would be great if you search a bit on that... It should work what I think... I never tried anything else.